# Is annotating a class with @Transactional the same as annotating all its methods as @Transactional?

Tags: grails

If I annotate a class with `@Transactional` like so:

```
@Transactional
class MyService { ... }
```

Is that the same as annotating all of its methods with `@Transactional` like so:

```
class MyService {
    @Transactional
    void myFunction() { ... }
}
```

There are also some other things to consider such as: how does this propagate to sub classes, inner classes, and static methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the
[documentation](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#declarativeTransactions)

> …The result is that all methods are wrapped in a transaction and
>   automatic rollback occurs if a method throws an exception (both Checked
>   or Runtime exceptions) or an Error…

So yes it is the same.

> how does this propagate to sub classes

It is inherited - but it is recommended to annotate only concrete classes

> inner classes

AFAIK not.
If any I would only define POJOs as an inner class - business logic
always goes into services

> static methods

AFAIK not